# How to check multiple existence of Column values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I have a table i.e. `Yearly_Author_CoAthors` having structure as:

```
Author  |  CoAuthor  |   Year  
------------------------------
677     |  901706    |   2005
677     |  38459     |   2007
677     |  901706    |   2007
677     |  1695352   |   2007
677     |  901706    |   2009
677     |  372089    |   2011
677     |  403400    |   2011
677     |  478885    |   2011
677     |  478885    |   2012
677     |  42700     |   2013
677     |  625964    |   2013
1359    |  133112    |   2005
1359    |  1412785   |   2005
1359    |  151268    |   2006
1359    |  232222    |   2007
1359    |  264864    |   2007  
...  
...
```

I have executed a query as:

```
SELECT * FROM Yearly_Author_CoAuthors
WHERE CoAuthor = 901706
```

It gives output as:

```
Author  |  CoAuthor  |  Year
----------------------------
677     |  901706    |  2005
677     |  901706    |  2007
677     |  901706    |  2009
1683703 |  901706    |  2012
```

It means the `CoAuthor = 901706` is associated with more than 1 `Author` i.e. 677 and 1683703.

So the question is:
*How can I modify this query to check all such `CoAuthor` who associated with more than 1 `Author`?*

Comment: `group by`, `having`, `count(1) > 1`

Comment: @HoneyBadger what will be the whole modified query ? For all CoAuthors having Authors more than 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using idea from Arulkumar, this query gave the expected result.

```
SELECT   CoAuthor, COUNT(DISTINCT Author) [AuthorCount], Year
FROM     Yearly_Author_CoAuthors
GROUP BY Year, CoAuthor
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT Author) > 1
ORDER BY CoAuthor, Year
```

Comment: Why the subselect ? You can simply query the table directly.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your given query as sub query, based on the result you can apply `GROUP BY` the Author column then check the `HAVING COUNT(Author) > 1`.

It will give your expected result:

```
SELECT Author, COUNT(Author) AuthorCount
FROM (
    SELECT Author, CoAuthor, [Year]
    FROM Yearly_Author_CoAuthors
    WHERE CoAuthor = 901706
) AC
GROUP BY Author
HAVING COUNT(Author) > 1
```

Comment: It is giving me this:  
`Author AuthorCount
677         3` ?

Comment: By using query `SELECT * FROM Yearly_Author_CoAuthors
WHERE CoAuthor = 901706` I found that `CoAuthor = 901706` has more than 1 `Author`, similarly I need the list of all `CoAuthor` who are having `Author` more than 1.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add your expected result?

Comment: I have mentioned that I need a list of CoAuthors probably with AuthorCount as second column and Year as third column

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a bit too much to write in a comment I'll put it here, but actually the answer of @maliks from 4 hours ago pretty much does the same thing.

I've changed the last 2 lines of the example data to get some results out of it.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('t_test') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE t_test
GO
CREATE TABLE t_test (Author int NOT NULL, CoAuthor int NOT NULL, Year int NOT NULL)
GO
INSERT t_test (Author, CoAuthor , Year)

SELECT 677     ,  901706    ,   2005 UNION ALL
SELECT 677     ,  38459     ,   2007 UNION ALL
SELECT 677     ,  901706    ,   2007 UNION ALL
SELECT 677     ,  1695352   ,   2007 UNION ALL
SELECT 677     ,  901706    ,   2009 UNION ALL
SELECT 677     ,  372089    ,   2011 UNION ALL
SELECT 677     ,  403400    ,   2011 UNION ALL
SELECT 677     ,  478885    ,   2011 UNION ALL
SELECT 677     ,  478885    ,   2012 UNION ALL
SELECT 677     ,  42700     ,   2013 UNION ALL
SELECT 677     ,  625964    ,   2013 UNION ALL
SELECT 1359    ,  133112    ,   2005 UNION ALL
SELECT 1359    ,  1412785   ,   2005 UNION ALL
SELECT 1359    ,  151268    ,   2006 UNION ALL
SELECT 1359    ,  901706    ,   2005 UNION ALL
SELECT 1359    ,  901706    ,   2007

GO

SELECT Year, CoAuthor, COUNT(DISTINCT Author)
  FROM t_test
 GROUP BY Year, CoAuthor
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Author) > 1
```